# What does the ". /etc/profile" do?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I saw these instructions in a book and don't know what the `. /etc/profile` command does, what is it?

Is it the same as `source /etc/profile`?

> #### Linux-specific Java steps
>
> On Linux systems, the following instructions set up a bash file in the
> `/etc/profile.d/` directory that defines `JAVA_HOME` for all users.
> Changing environmental settings in this folder requires root access
> and affects all users of the system. (We’re using `$` as the bash
> shell prompt.) The Oracle JVM installer typically installs the
> software in `/usr/java/ jdk-1.6.X` (for v1.6) and it creates sym-links
> from `/usr/java/default` and `/usr/java/latest` to the installation:
>
> ```
> $ /usr/java/latest/bin/java -version
> java version "1.6.0_23"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_23-b05)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
> $ sudo echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest" > /etc/profile.d/java.sh
> $ sudo echo "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" >> /etc/profile.d/java.sh
> $ . /etc/profile
> $ echo $JAVA_HOME
> /usr/java/latest
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `. /etc/profile` is the same as `source /etc/profile` as you said. It means the commands in the file will be executed as they were executed in cli, and not in a new subshell as with standard script being called.

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html

> 3.5. Sourcing a File When a file is sourced (by typing either source filename or . filename at the command line), the lines of code in the
> file are executed as if they were printed at the command line. This is
> particularly useful with complex prompts, to allow them to be stored
> in files and called up by sourcing the file they are in.
>
> In examples, you will find that I often include #!/bin/bash at the
> beginning of files including functions. This is not necessary if you
> are sourcing a file, just as it isn't necessary to chmod +x a file
> that is going to be sourced. I do this because it makes Vim (my editor
> of choice, no flames please - you use what you like) think I'm editing
> a shell script and turn on colour syntax highlighting.